# Disable Google Chrome address autocomplete in a Formik Field - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, field, formik

I have a form in Formik ReactJs, which receives data to fill addresses.
[Field Formik](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYu7S.png)

However, when a person has addresses added in Google Chrome, the form comes out as follows:
[Field Formik with autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8y6J.png)

How can I remove autocomplete from my Field?
I have tried with: `autocomplete="off"` and it does not work.

Here mi Field:

```
          <Field
            component={FormikAutocomplete}
            name="countryArea"
            noOptionsText={i18n._(t`No options`)}
            options={counties.map(c => c.name)}
            disableClearable
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) =>
              option.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()
            }
            textFieldProps={{
              fullWidth: true,
              label: i18n._(t`Province / State / Region`),
              variant,
            }}
            disabled={disabled}
          />
```

Any doubt about the code, I am attentive to solve it to receive a better help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

should provide autoComplete="some-random-name" and it works fine on formik

```
         <Field
            component={FormikAutocomplete}
            name="countryArea"
            autoComplete="new-country-area"
            noOptionsText={i18n._(t`No options`)}
            options={counties.map(c => c.name)}
            disableClearable
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) =>
              option.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()
            }
            textFieldProps={{
              fullWidth: true,
              label: i18n._(t`Province / State / Region`),
              variant,
            }}
            disabled={disabled}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that chrome relies on the name of the field for autocompletion, have you tried to put something less obvious than "countryArea"? Like:

```js
const Basic = () => {
  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <span>With autocomplete</span>
        <input type="text" name="countryArea" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Without autocomplete</span>
        <input type="text" name="ctryAr" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>With autocomplete</span>
        <input type="text" name="phone" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Without autocomplete</span>
        <input type="text" name="phne" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Basic />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="react" />
```